# Visual Studio Online TFS Sync Framework

Tags: azure-devops

**Update** Fixed by moving the build server on premises so I could install sync framework. The build queue can still be managed in Visual Studio Team Services.

I have a TF project hosted on Visual Studio Online. It depends on the NuGet package for Microsoft Sync Framework. According to the NuGet [documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build), Visual Studio online will automatically perform a NuGet package restore when building the solutions.

Unfortunately, assembly references to Microsoft.Synchronization.* are not working:

```
42>ResolveAssemblyReferences:
    Primary reference "Microsoft.Synchronization.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL".
42>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Synchronization.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\src\SomeProject.csproj]
```

Other NuGet packages like MoreLinq and EPPlus are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Nuget package and the references and then adding it again.

Often I find there is one person on the team that does not "get" Nugget and adds the reference manually...

Comment: Thanks. What I ultimately ended up doing was configuring on premises build controllers and build agents, and installing sync framework on the server that hosts them. That took care of the build failtures.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that NuGet restore in fact downloads msi file, not the libraries themselves, and after download is done it doesn't execute the msi.

So additionally you need to run cmd\powershell to execute this msi installer, before starting the build.
In my case it was Azure DevOps MS hosted agent (but i guess it's similar to VSO) and it puts the package in the next directory:

`D:\a\1\s\packages\Microsoft.SyncFramework.2.1.0.2\tools\x64\` - folder may vary, but you got the idea.

And then just execute the installer with quiet argument, so agent installs it silently:

```
Synchronization-v2.1-x64-ENU.msi /quiet
```

Then start building your project\solution.